# How can I program something that asks two integers from the user and displays it in the following sequence in C++?

Tags: c++, input

I'm a kind of beginner in C++ and need little help here.
How can I create a C++ program which takes two integers from the user and It displays the sequence in this format using Nested Loops:

Enter the starting integer: 11

Enter the ending integer: 18

(11,11)(11,12)(11,13)(11,14)(11,15)(11,16)(11,17)(11,18)

(12,12)(12,13)(12,14)(12,15)(12,16)(12,17)

(13,13)(13,14)(13,15)(13,16)

(14,14)(14,15)

or

Enter the starting integer: 1

Enter the ending integer: 5

(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(1,5)

(2,2)(2,3)(2,4)

(3,3)

I wrote the code something like this before:

```
int startingval;
    cout << "Enter starting integer: ";
    cin >> startingval;

    int endingval;
    cout << "Enter Ending integer: ";
    cin >> endingval;

    int looptime;
    looptime = endingval;

    endingval = startingval;



    for (int i = 0; i < startingval; i++)
    {

            cout << "(" << startingval << ", " << endingval << ")";
            endingval++;

            if (endingval == looptime + 1)
            {
                i = startingval;
       }

    }




    return 0;
```

But, This is not what I need. Please Help me :)

Comment: If you're using C++, why did you use the C and C# tags too?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Since you've tagged C#, can I safely assume that an answer in C# will be sufficient for you?

Comment: Yeah, Sorry! This is my first post in here that's why 

Comment: I've got the solution. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you can't use any tags except that's in your question.
the only difference between the sequence you want and the normal nested loop between all elements in the array is the ending point is decreesing 
I suggest you try the following code:

```
int start;
cout << "Enter starting integer: ";
cin >> start;
int end;
cout << "Enter Ending integer: ";
cin >> end;
for(int i=start;i<=end;i++){
    for(int j=i;j<=end;j++)
        cout << "(" << i << ", " << j << ")";
    cout<<endl;
    end--;
}
```

I hope be useful, Let me know if there is a problem.